# Как работает алгоритм обратного распространения ошибки?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Может ли кто - либо доходчиво объяснить мне, как работает алгоритм обратного распространения ошибки?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOmkv5SI9hU если по видео будут вопросы, задавайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: BackProp]

1. Считается прямое распространение(FP). Стандартно: просуммировали вход на каждый нейрон слоя с учётом весов, прибавили элемент смещения и активировали. И так от слоя к слою.
2. Обратное распространение (BP) заключается в том, что после пункта (1) подсчитываются ошибки на всех слоях, кроме входного, начиная с выходного и по цепочке к началу. При расчете этих ошибок используются формулы с производными соответствующих функций активации.
3. Полученные ошибки используются для расчета градиентов, которые потом - для изменения весов.